# do while syntax for java

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

Ages since I have written a do while.

Whats wrong with this do while

```
int i = 0;
    do { 
        System.out.println(i);
    } while(++i == 500);
```

I only goes once through the loop, and IMO it should iterate 500 times.

Comment: it should be "equal to" 500 that many times?

Comment: How many times will i equal 500 if it starts at 0? A print statement or a debugger would have answered this immediately.

Comment: -1 for not even trying to find out yourself what’s wrong.

Comment: Frack! Of course. I still don't understand the down votes. Its an honest blunder :/

Comment: Maybe I'm a little rude here but... your profile says Senior Java Developer.... hmmm.... PS: The downvotes are probably because you should've tried to figure it out on your own, not jump straight to stackoverflow.

Comment: @Bombe I have tried the last half hour to figure out

Comment: @SoboLAN Sometimes it's too obvious and you are not looking in the right place. Taking a step back or starting to ask the question is often enough. In some occasions, you might even go as far as validating the question. ;-)

Comment: @Shervin: Have you tried using a debugger? It should have told you that `i != 500` at the end of the loop.

Comment: @NiklasB. of course I did. I thought a do while was `do this until i == 500` but its the oposite. Thats why I didnt understand why it only went once in the loop

Comment: @Shervin: Well `while` is pretty much the opposite of `until`, isn't it? ;) Anyway, glad you figured it out now.

Comment: I think the downvotes are because looking up the semantics is really easy.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You probably meant

```
while (++i < 500);
```

instead of

```
while (++i == 500);
```

Answer (score 14):

It is a `do-while` loop of Java, not the `repeat-until` loop of Pascal. Its expression specifies the *continuation condition*, not the *exit condition*.

```
do { 
    System.out.println(i);
} while(++i != 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

It will only iterate once because of your condition. `while (++i == 500)` `++i` will be 1 and never 500, so it evaluates to false and won't continue.

Comment: You are right, I should actually look at the numbers first. It won't be 2, but it will never be 500.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(++i != 500)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

is the better way.

Answer (score 0):

In your code initially the value of i (i.e. 0) will be printed because it is a do while and the code inside the loop should be executed at least once.
And then now the condition will be checked. It will be checked that if ++i equals 500 (i.e 1==500) which returns false and hence the loop breaks.

while (++i < 500);

changing the condition to the above statement may cause the loop to continue untill the value of i becomes 500