# how to make program restart after incorrect input java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program restart at a certain point if the wrong email address is input so users won't have to fully restart the program in case they spelt something wrong and didn't notice.  this is what I have so far

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String grade = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Specify Your Grade");
    String First_name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your First Name?");
    String Last_name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your Last Name?");
    String message = "You are a " + grade + "\n"
            + "Your Name is " + First_name + " " + Last_name;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, message);
    String email = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "enter email");
        if (email.contains("@branfordschools.org")){                
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Password Accepted");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Password Incorrect, Program Closing");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

Seeing that java doesn't have GOTO (Was gonna use it until it caused problems, program is only for a graduation presentation) how would I go about making it go back to here?

```
    String email = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "enter email");
        if (email.contains("@branfordschools.org")){                
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Password Accepted");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Password Incorrect, Program Closing");
            System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Use a Do-While loop.Google it.Basic stuff.

Comment: The concept you are looking for are called **loops**. In other words: some built-in replacement for gotos. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834202/do-while-syntax-for-java for example

Comment: You probably want endsWith() instead of contains. Because your current code logic would greenlight @brandfordschool.orgRANDOMSTUFF with no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple while loop that will continue to ask for an email until it contains "@branfordschools.org"

```
    String email;
    Boolean validEmail = False;

    while(!validEmail)
    {
        //ask the user for the email
        email = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "enter email");
        if (email.contains("@branfordschools.org")){                
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Password Accepted");
            validEmail = True;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Password Incorrect, Please Re-Enter Password");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work;

```
 boolean validInput = false;
    while (!validInput) {
        String email = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter email");
        if (email.contains("@branfordschools.org")) {
            validInput = true;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password Accepted");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password Incorrect, Program Closing");
        }
    }
```